# Find whether user is online or not with CI_Session

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

I'm working on chat module for my project with ajax. I would like to find out whether that user is online or not

I am using below shown DB Table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ci_sessions` (
    `id` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    `ip_address` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    `timestamp` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    `data` blob NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    KEY `ci_sessions_timestamp` (`timestamp`)
);
```

And This config data in config.php

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
```

After that I could not able to find how data inserted into that table. I am thinking that it will be inserted directly into that database table. But db table has been empty since half a day. Can anybody suggest me what should I do next

Answer (score 0):

First of all, to use database driver for session handling, these conditions must be met;

- Only your default database connection (or the one that you access as
  $this->db from your controllers) can be used.
- You must have the Query Builder enabled.
- You can NOT use a persistent connection.
- You can NOT use a connection with the cache_on setting enabled.

And then you must create a table for storing session data;

```html
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ci_sessions` (
        `id` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
        `ip_address` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
        `timestamp` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
        `data` blob NOT NULL,
        KEY `ci_sessions_timestamp` (`timestamp`)
);
```

You don't need to add primary key to this table because your option 'sess_match_ip' is set to FALSE.